# "Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager" with almost the most recent version

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, webdriver

I've tried writing this code on my jupyter notebook, and it shows me the error. My objective is to carry out web scrapping.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()
```

I get the following error:

```
NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I have the following version of selenium:

```
selenium.__version__
'4.15.2'
```

Could this problem be related to the fact that I am working from a corp network and I need root privileges to run this code? Or do I necessarily need selenium version 4.16?